# Remove scripts at bottom of page added by Yahoo?

Tags: javascript, html, yahoo

I'm using Yahoo Small Business to host my website. I use an FTP client (FileZila) to upload my files. However at the end of every page is these few lines:

```
</html>
<!-- text below generated by server. PLEASE REMOVE -->
<!-- Counter/Statistics data collection code -->
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://us.js2.yimg.com/us.js.yimg.com/lib/smb/js/hosting/cp/js_source/whv2_001.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">geovisit();</script>
<noscript>
    <img src="http://visit.webhosting.yahoo.com/visit.gif?us1264993801" alt="setstats" border="0" width="1" height="1">
</noscript>
```

Everytime I remove it, it comes back. The comment says to remove it. Why the heck can't I remove this. *As a side not this is the only thing keeping my site from validating as valid HTML 5.*

Answer (score 2):

My guess is, it is generated by Yahoo's SB engine for tracking purposes. If you were to download the file and edit, the comment stated that you remove those lines so that Yahoo engine will add it again upon upload.

PS: I really don't think Yahoo Small Business cares about HTML5 validation.

Comment: @o.k.w: I hear that. I don't think they care much about validation at all.

Answer (score 2):

I was just fixing a Yahoo SE site for a friend and that script is a Yahoo tracker.  To remove it, go into the "web hosting control panel", "site statistics", then click the options button in the top right.  Remove the "statistics" option and you're good to go.

It's now Validating HTML5 - Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

That same code was causing upward of 75-second delays on all my pages starting two days ago -- it calls for a one-pixel image located at https://visit.webhosting.yahoo.com/visit.gif
(you can see the image tag in skaffman's question above -- next-to-last line) but that particular link has been broken for the past three days. The result is that every page that has an onload script will hang before it can run the script, as the Yahoo code preempts the page's onload scripts.

My solution was to call Yahoo customer service and have them disable the site statistics (which now also means that I can no longer track usage of my site via their hosting interface).

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo no longer give you the option to be rid of that code snippet. We're stuck with it until they are no longer our ISP.  That will be soon.